Modifications not propagating through object reference
Here since the pointers fast and slow are referencing the same object dummy, why do the modificaitons in slow donot modify the fast pointer?


function ListNode(val, next) {
  this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
  this.next = (next === undefined ? null : next)
}

var removeNthFromEnd = function(head, n) {
  let dummy = new ListNode(0);
  dummy.next = head;

  let slow = dummy;
  let fast = dummy;
  slow = slow.next
  console.log(fast)

  for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    fast = fast.next;
  }

  while (fast !== null) {
    slow = slow.next;
    fast = fast.next;
  }

  return dummy.next;
};

removeNthFromEnd({
  val: 1,
  next: {
    val: 2,
    next: {
      val: 3,
      next: {
        val: 4,
        next: {
          val: 5,
          next: null
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, 2)



This type of behaviour  does not occur when i directly assign object to variables

Because you changed the value of slow to slow.next, so then it is no longer referencing dummy.

@Pointy so here if i change the slow.next, then all the variables referencing dummy will also be updated?

Yes, if slow.next is also equal to dummy. It might be null, looking at your code.

@Pointy that helped, thanks

Assignments propagate through references if you modify the object that's referenced, not when you modify the variable itself.

If you know C or C++, you can think of the variable as being like a pointer to a struct. Reassigning a pointer doesn't affect other pointers to the same struct.
